# Does dataflow support custom triggers or updating trigger delays?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

TL:DR; Is it possible to create a custom trigger that only fires if some flag is set? Is it possible to deploy the job with a trigger with a huge delay while we know a large data event is happening, and then deploy an update to the job with the trigger having a normal or no delay once that event is finished?

Following on from: [Remove duplicates across window triggers/firings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38234741/remove-duplicates-across-window-triggers-firings)

The situation where this happens the most problematically (millions of duplicate firings) is when we're doing a backfill of old data. Given we know when this was happening I was wondering if we could implement a custom trigger that doesn't fire while a flag is set. Is that something that would be possible? Alternatively, could we deploy the job with a trigger that includes a huge delay while backfill is going on, and then issue an update with the normal trigger when it's finished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dataflow does not yet support custom triggers, or triggers based on some separate piece of metadata.  However, you can change the frequency of a processing time trigger with Update; just change the value of the plusDelay() builder function and run with --update as normal.

Comment: Just a follow up, after the update, does that mean all groupby's that were previously waiting on the trigger will be fired? Or will they not fire until a new piece of data comes into the window?

Comment: They will fire either after the old timeout if no new data shows up, or after the new timeout if new data does show up